# Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection node js mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

---

I am getting this error. after some time. I think this error comes because MySQL is in idle. anyone suggest me to prevent this error.

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.end (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/invoice/invoice2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi when you connect mysql with normal connection with node js server , after some time your mysql client will down 
so you have to connect to mysql server with **pooling** mechanism.

Please go through here you can find the how to connect mysql with pooling connection 
(https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for connection protocol lost. This solution solved me

Here the data base connection

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'******',
    database:'db_name'
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error) console.log(error);
     else console.log('SQL Database Connected!');
});

module.exports = connection;`
```

just run the node server using pm2, for example:
`pm2 start app.js`

Ref: [Install the npm pm2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)